# Calculating the relative gradient and offset of two lines with restricted information

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Suppose I have two straight lines, $y_1 = m_1(x+c_1)$ and $y_2=m_2(x+c_2)$, and I do not know the coefficients $m_1, m_2, c_1$ or $c_2$.

I am given a series of measurements of $y_1$ and $y_2$ that both correspond to the same value of $x$, but I do not know the value of $x$ itself for each measurement.

Is it possible to calculate a best estimate for the relative gradient and offset between lines 1 and 2?

For reference, I have already solved the simpler problem whereby I have $N$ lines and I know the gradients for each one, and wanted to find the relative offsets between the zeroth and $n$th lines ($0<n<N$). To do this, I solved a matrix equation of the form $Ax=y$, premultiplied both sides by $A^T$, and rearranged for $x$.

In that problem, I found an vector of length $N-1$ of relative offsets. I was wondering whether I could use a similar principle to solve this question posed above, but with a vector of length $2(N-1)$, and I am struggling to see how one might construct the vector in a way that allows me to construct a matrix equation as I previously did.

Am I wasting my time on a problem that can't be solved?